# Trying to create a db to a different local postgres server

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

In my server cluster in pgAdmin I have created 3 different servers. Everytime I create a database through psycopg2, it is being created on all 3 of them. I think this makes sense as when I create the servers they only differ in their name, all the other parameters are the same. host:localhost, port:5432, username:postgres.

Is there a way to create a database to a specific one?

My ini file in psycopg2 looks like this:

```
[postgresql]
host=localhost
user=postgres
port=5432
password=*
```

Comment: do you have specific schema ?  or have you pass `dbname` args into your connect method? looks like `postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@host:port/dbname` or `conn = psycopg2.connect(host="...",  dbname="...",  user="...", password="...", port='...')`

Comment: @AshkanGolehPour I pass dbname if I want to connect to an existing database. Here I am just trying to create one.

Comment: No this does not make sense as there can only be one server listening on a given port on a given host.  You need to 1) **Add to your question** the actual code you are using to create the database. 2) Verify that the 'servers' in `pgAdmin` are not actually all pointing to the same Postgres server.